# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I try to get the number of object within an array but I got  'length' of undefined.

My js

```
..
      success: function(data){
        console.log(data.item.length);
      },
```

My PHP

```
<?php
   $arr = array();
   $arr["item"]["book"] = "harry porter";
   $arr["item"]["available"] = true;

   echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

output

```
{"item":{"book":"harry porter","available":true}}
```

Comment: What is the `dataType` of your request? It seems the data is not parsed by jQuery.  After parsing the console will show `undefined` as arrays have `length` property not objects.

Comment: in your ajax request if you add dataType: "json" then it should work

Answer (score 1):

All content sent via HTTP(S) requests are received as strings (in Ajax, at least). When you receive a string that's in JavaScript's Object format, it's called JSON.  You need to parse this JSON back into a readable JavaScript object.

You would need to use the `JSON.parse` function, this turns JSON into a JavaScript Object.
Also `.length` only works on arrays not on object so you need to use `console.log(Object.keys(data).length);`

Your function would look like:

```
data=JSON.parse(data);
console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
data = {"item":{"book":"harry porter","available":true}};
alert(Object.keys(data.item).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the JSON string to a JSON object before operating on it.

```
var obj = eval ("(" + data + ")");
```

BTW, I see that item is not an array. If you want to make it an array, it has to be like this

```
{item : [{"book" : "harry potter", "available" : true}, {..}]}
```

Comment: why? I thought my PHP produced an array?

Comment: If u see ur output, it's not generating the output in array format

Answer (score 0):

*I try to get the number of object within an array*

In the success callback you have got a js object and you want to get the number of `objects` inside it. so when you do `data.item.length` it goes to check the length of the js object which is not available for it.

Instead you have to check for the keys names of js object like `item` which is available in your callback `data` object. So the piece of code you are looking for is this:

```
Object.keys(data).length
```

this will count the keys name of `{"item":{}}`, so in your case you just have one *(1)*.

```js
var obj = {"item":{"book":"harry porter","available":true}};
alert(Object.keys(obj).length)
```

so in your success callback you can do this:

```
  success: function(data){
    console.log(Object.keys(data).length);
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert(Object.keys(data).length);
```

your code may like this

```
$.ajax({
url: "items.php",
type: "POST",
dataType: "JSON",
success: function(data) {
data=JSON.parse(data);
alert(Object.keys(data).length); 
});
```